# move elements of ul to the left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am designing a carousel. I have completed the HTML and CSS markups but don't know how to move the elements to the right or left by one element. It's important that the viewport all ways show 7 pictures.

```css
.seccion {
    max-height: 700px;
    min-height: 700px;
}
div.animacionCel {
    height: 60%;
    min-height: 60%;
    max-height: 60%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
div.viewport {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}
ul.slides {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-table;

    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -ms-transition: all 1s;
    -o-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
}
ul.slides > li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;

    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -ms-transition: all 1s;
    -o-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
}
ul.slides > li > img {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 90%;
    width: 14.28%;
}
ul.slides > li.activo > img {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 14.28%;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head> </head>
    <body>
        <!-- second section -->
        <section class="seccion center-block">
            <div class="animacionCel center-block">
                <div class="viewport">
                    <ul class="slides">
                        <li><img src="../images/screen_cel_1.png"/></li>
                        <li><img src="../images/screen_cel_2.png"/></li>
                        <li><img src="../images/screen_cel_3.png"/></li>
                        <li class="activo"><img src="../images/screen_cel_4.png"/></li>
                        <li><img src="../images/screen_cel_5.png"/></li>
                        <li><img src="../images/screen_cel_6.png"/></li>
                        <li><img src="../images/screen_cel_7.png"/></li>
                        <li><img src="../images/screen_cel_8.png"/></li>
                        <li><img src="../images/screen_cel_9.png"/></li>
                        <li><img src="../images/screen_cel_10.png"/></li>
                        <li><img src="../images/screen_cel_11.png"/></li>
                        <li><img src="../images/screen_cel_12.png"/></li>
                        <li><img src="../images/screen_cel_13.png"/></li>
                        <li><img src="../images/screen_cel_14.jpg"/></li>
                        <li><img src="../images/screen_cel_15.png"/></li>
                        <li><img src="../images/screen_cel_16.jpg"/></li>
                        <li><img src="../images/screen_cel_17.jpg"/></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried using JQuery animate.

Comment: Are you trying to make one horizontal row taking up 100% of the viewport and hiding all others?

Comment: out of curiosity, can you not use an existing library? There's so many good carousel libs out there

Comment: how do you want it to scroll left and right? are they clicking on something, is it on a timer?

Comment: I,ve tried to use some libs but don't correspond to what I need, and change them or adapt them would be more difficult

Comment: It will move automatically with a timer

Comment: Is it inifinite then? Your code has 17 slides which is not divisible by 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSFiddle Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/tkrwagkL/1/

**JQuery**

```
window.setInterval(rotateLI, 1000); //1 second

function rotateLI() {
    var x = $('ul.slides li').first().remove();     //Remove the first element, we'll append it to the end
    $('ul.slides li.activo').removeClass('activo'); //Take off the active class, we'll put it on the new center
    var ctr = $('ul.slides li').get(4);             //Get the new center li
    $(ctr).addClass('activo');                      //Add the active class to the center element
    $('ul.slides').append(x);                       //Append the remove element to the list
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't detach() be the better function to call over remove()? That way, any events or data bound to the element would be preserved. Additionally, you could just call $('ul.slides').append($('ul.slides li').first()); to immediately move it. It won't affect the .get(4) call.

Comment: All valid :-), I just wrote up a *quick* solution, wasn't concerned about optomization

Comment: :) Consider my comments more of an addendum to your answer for those who read and not a correction. Because, indeed, it is valid.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i apreciate the corrections, this is my second post so  they are all welcome